# Javascript Array of objects - how do i loop through and get the object values

Tags: javascript

Im having some issues creating an array of objects in javascript

Please see my code below and tell me where im going wrong..

I simply want to loop through and access the values

```
<!-- Read XML Script -->
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Object array
    var myArray = [];

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "HighScore.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function (xml) {
                $(xml).find('challenger').each(function () {

                    var name = $(this).find('Name').text();
                    var watts = $(this).find('Watts').text();
                    var Mins = $(this).find('Mins').text();

                    // objects in the array
                    challenger = new Object();
                    challenger.name = name;
                    challenger.watts = watts;
                    challenger.Mins = Mins;

                    myArray.push(challenger);

                });

                // look into the array
                for (obj in myArray) {
                    // do i need to cast ?? how can i view the object ??
                    alert(obj + " - ");
                }


            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "view the object"? Do you mean how can you perform `alert` with its properties?

Comment: yes, access its properties :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for .. in ..` works different in javascript than in some other languages. Instead of the object, you will get the key. In your array therefore you'll get the index.

For iterating over arrays, just use an index-based array to avoid hassle:

```
for (var ix = 0; ix < myArray.length; ix++) {
    var obj = myArray[ix];

    alert(obj.name);
}
```

If you really want to use the `for .. in ..` syntax, use this:

```
var a = ['jan', 'klaas']; 
for(var key in a) { 
    if (a.hasOwnProperty(key)) { 
        console.log(a[key].name); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-                for (obj in myArray) {
-                    // do i need to cast ?? how can i view the object ??
-                    alert(obj + " - ");
-                }

+                for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
+                    var obj = myArray[i];
+                    // do i need to cast ?? how can i view the object ??
+                    alert(JSON.stringify(obj, null, '  '));
+                }
```